# Clarify the How To Ask sidebar first sentence

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I think that the How To Ask sidebar https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

> Is your question about music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history?

should be changed to

> Questions here should be about music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history.

This is more clear I think.

Does anybody disagree? If not, can this be installed? Can a similar change be installed on Meta?

Comment: Not at all. I think it's perfectly clear in question form, and more friendly to new users as well.

Comment: You should discuss this on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead, or perhaps ask a moderator to migrate it there by flagging your question. Because I belief that this question isn't really specific to our site alone...